# ClassCastException - an ADT bug?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

Well it might seem silly.. but now this is driving me insane. I have an `AutoCompleteTextView` that looks like:

```
     <AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/etActionSearch"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/LinearLayout2"
    android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:drawablePadding="7dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:hint="start typing a name"
    android:inputType="textFilter"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

It USED to be an `EditText` a while ago, but then I just changed the XML per hand (to be an `AutoCompleteTextView`) without deleting the `View` and creating it again. I reference it in code:

```
  private AutoCompleteTextView etActionSearch; //class field
  etActionSearch = (AutoCompleteTextView) actionBar.getCustomView()
            .findViewById(R.id.etActionSearch);
    etActionSearch.setThreshold(1);
```

And now the issue: on the device I used to test the app since it was created everything's working fine. Now I send the project to a mate of me, he runs it on a device running same Android version:

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.EditText cannot be cast to android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView
```

I send him an exported .apk, same issue, crash. I install the **SAME** .apk on my device, everything's working fine. I run this code on the emulator (1st time running on emulator) - same `Exception`, crash. I deleted `R.java`, the gen folder, cleaned the project multiple times, the issue still remains.... I only ask: what the hell is going on?

**SOLVED** suggestion: don't code at night

Comment: I usually see this exception after moving the widgets around in xml. But that doesn't seem to be the issue here.

Comment: yep, had similar issues after moving Views, but clean always helped. Now it's not the case and this annoys me as hell

Comment: It's a long shot: do you use multiple layout folders, `layout-land` etc.? Is it possible that you changed the widget in one, but the other still holds an `EditText`?

Comment: oh goddammit. I should stop coding when the clock shows 3 a.m.... I totally forgot about the layout-sw400dp folder. Thanks dude, post this as an answer and I'll accept it. *_facepalm_*

Comment: `It's a long shot: do you use multiple layout.........but the other still holds an EditText?`I WAS ALMOST NOT GOING TO POST THIS COMMENT.

Comment: I'm glad you did it, I'd waste a couple of hours debugging the thing otherwise ><

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes to widgets in a layout file should be reflected in corresponding files residing in other `res/layout-*` folders. Or, these changes should be handled appropriately in code.